# Express 4 node js , Access session data in public javascript file

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express

I need to use a session data in one of my javascript file in the public folder,
but i can't access it , i did try to make session global,

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.locals.session = req.session;
    next();
});
```

but that doesn't make any defferent

Comment: Is your session working fine?try to console req.session and check if there is any value.

Comment: @PPB i tried but i get session is not defined , it's working fine in view files i can access it from there

Comment: Where is your session middleware relative to this `app.use()`? It should come *before* this middleware.